# Blazor: Render HTML based on pattern matching switch statement

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, blazor

I'd like to use pattern matching instead of a series of if-elseif statements to select what HTML to render in a Blazor page.

I did find a way to do it, but it's awkward

```cs
@{
   RenderFragment r = cellProgress?.progressPercent switch  
   {
      null => @<i />,
      0 => @<i />,
      1 => @<i>O</i>,
      _ => @<i>@cellProgress.progressPercent.ToString("P0")</i>,
   };
}
@r
```

The compiler can't infer a type without the `RenderFragment` assignment.

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This might be slightly less awkward:

```
@Progress(cellProgress?.progressPercent)

...

@code
{
   RenderFragment Progress(int? p) = p switch  
   {
      null => @<i />,
      0 => @<i />,
      1 => @<i>O</i>,
      _ => @<i>@p.ToString("P0")</i>,
   };
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Not quite what I was hoping for, it removes the markup from context. But it's probably the right way to go if the decision is in more than one place

Answer (score 0):

The following may look a bit cleaner (although still slightly awkward):

```csharp
@code{
    private static double? progressPercent = 0.24;

    private static RenderFragment r = progressPercent switch
    {
        null => EmptyI,
        0 => EmptyI,
        1 => IWithO,
        _ => IWithPercent(progressPercent.Value)
    };

    private static RenderFragment EmptyI => @<i />;
    private static RenderFragment IWithO => @<i>O</i>;
    private static RenderFragment IWithPercent(double percent) => @<i>@percent.ToString("P0")</i>;
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vwrjty1t).